# AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager' is not defined

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am upgrading from .Net Framework 4.0 to 4.5 and i get this error

```
'AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager' is not defined
```

The code with the error:

```
Protected WithEvents ToolkitScriptManager1 As Global.AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager
```

It doesn't allow me to use ToolkitScriptManager anymore..
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you try to use the regular `<asp:ScriptManager></asp:ScriptManager>` .

Here you can see some info about what I am talking about. https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ToolkitScriptManager%20Removed%20in%20v15.1%2C%20Use%20ScriptManager